# Two or more threads on single core

Tags: debian, embedded, c, multithreading

What are the advantages of using threads on single core, does that makes sense to use multithreading on single core?

Comment: might be a good question for http://embedded.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is far too little context here to give a good answer, but for most reasonable contexts the answer is "probably yes". The operating system itself runs many things in parallell on that single core, after all, and you'd be pretty darn annoyed if you had to wait for some web page to finish loading before your mouse pointer would move.

Comment: But threads rotate one after another, just too fast so we think that it works parallel, am I right?

Comment: Yes. You won't get true concurrency without more than one execution unit.